# Overriding 1 external stylesheet with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering if there is a way to simply override one external style sheet over another. I am using bootstrap only for the modal -- and inserting their style sheet has overridden a good deal of my current layout's styles. As opposed to downloading the bootstrap file, unminifiying it and searching for the conflicting styles, or throwing my previous global .css inline in the `<head>`; I'm wondering if there is simply one technique I can use to allow style sheet A.) to override style sheet B.) in areas of conflict, or with similar ids or class names.

I have tried rearranging the orders, but haven't had success.

Comment: One way would be just customize your download to include JUST the Modal CSS here:  http://getbootstrap.com/customize/.

Comment: Maybe it's something deeper hard to tell without seeing your structure but for me I compile my bootstrap and main styles in one minified CSS. Always compile my CSS after all of bootstrap.

Comment: I'm learning to let bootstrap handle most of everything this is huge for me http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups if anything needs to look more custom and sexy try to make the changes like `border` etc as minimaly invasive as possible. Best thing I ever did was use bootstrap SASS and create a file to override the variables which controls pretty much all of bootstrap.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but you could always hit up http://csslint.net/

Comment: Might not be helpful for you now, but maybe in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct jOshT you can just select the CSS for modal. [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Rather than trying to override your style sheet, copy and paste the styles from Bootstrap's CSS modal styles into your own, then you won't have multiple style sheets to override.